How to, in a single shot, update a child embedded document in multiple records of a single MongoDB collection based on array of records?
I have a list of objects as such:
[
   { 
       "UserId": 100,
       ....
       Statistics: { ... }
   },
   { 
       "UserId": 200,
       ....
       Statistics: { ... }
   },
   { 
       "UserId": 300,
       ....
       Statistics: { ... }
   },
]

It is possible, in one shot, to create an update/filter statement which would replace the "Statistics" embedded document (while keeping all other fields as they are) for each one of the users. Each user has its own data in the "Statistics".  I am using the C# MongoDB driver.
I understand if I want an atomic operation I might have to use a session, but excluding a session, and if I am Ok with the operation not being atomic, just performant, is there anyway to do the above mentioned update without a for loop for each user?
Reading through the documentation I do not see a way to handle this, but the C# driver documentation only go over basic use cases.

You can perform a bulk write to update multiple documents with a single statement:
var updates = new List<UpdateOneModel<User>>(3);
updates.Add(new UpdateOneModel<User>(Builders<User>.Filter.Eq(x => x.UserId, 100), 
                  Builders<User>.Update.Set(x => x.Statistics, newStatsUser100)));
updates.Add(new UpdateOneModel<User>(Builders<User>.Filter.Eq(x => x.UserId, 200), 
                  Builders<User>.Update.Set(x => x.Statistics, newStatsUser200)));
updates.Add(new UpdateOneModel<User>(Builders<User>.Filter.Eq(x => x.UserId, 300), 
                  Builders<User>.Update.Set(x => x.Statistics, newStatsUser300)));
await coll.BulkWriteAsync(updates, new() { IsOrdered = false });

Above sample creates a list of update statements that each update one document and assign a new value to the Statistics property. The updates are finally written using the BulkWriteAsync method. Setting IsOrdered to false asserts that even if an error occurs, all the successful updates are carried out.
However, unless you are using a session with a transaction, the operation is only atomic for each document.

Great, this is what I was looking for. I wonder if there is a kind of "unit of work" pattern which can be developed when using MongoDB driver where you collect all the Update/Replace/Insert models into a collection at then at the end of the "request" call "Save", which would do the BulkWriteAsync and potentially wrap that BulkWriteAsync in a session. Kind of how Entity Framework collects all changes, but only applies them when SaveChanges() is called.

You may have a look at MongoDB Entity Framework Core Provider. Maybe it is just what you are looking for.

I did. On this current project I started with the EF Core provider, but it had some bugs and some features which it didnt implement but I required, so I rewrote everything to just use the C# driver.
